# Populate data from csv to room database kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to populate data from CSV to room database using kotlin in Android. I tried to convert the java code to Kotlin from this [Populate Room database using csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51622277/populate-room-database-using-csv-file), but I am not able to access the Dao. Is there any better way to populate data from csv using Kotlin.

```
 @Database(
            entities = [MenuItem::class,
                Order::class,
                OrderItem::class,
                Restaurant::class,
                RestaurantRating::class,
                User::class,
                UserFavorite::class,
                UserSearch::class],
            version = 15,
            exportSchema = false)
    
    
    abstract class AppDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    
        abstract val orderDao: OrderDao
        abstract val restaurantDao: RestaurantDao
        abstract val userDao: UserDao
    
        companion object{
    
            @Volatile
            private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null
    
            fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
                synchronized(this) {
                    var instance = INSTANCE
    
                    if (instance == null) {
                        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                                context.applicationContext,
                                AppDatabase::class.java,
                                "foodie_database.db"
                        )
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback(){
                                override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                                    super.onCreate(db)
                                    
                                    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute {
                                        run {
                                            
                                        }
                                    }
    
    
                                }
                            })
    
                                .build()
                        INSTANCE = instance
                    }
                    return instance
                }
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to pre-populate your database on first app startup. I didn't look into exactly how you can get access to the dao manually but the java example you pointed to I believe is using dagger dependency injection to get an instance of the dao.
How to overcome the circular dependency for a callback from Room.databaseBuilder using Dagger Hilt is wonderfully explained in a Code in flow video ([link](https://youtu.be/eVsiefsFuoQ)). I think this will give you enough information to figure out how to make the callback work.

Alternatively, and this is the one I prefer, you can use a database file instead of the csv file and use Room's inbuilt pre-population feature.
Just call `.createFromAsset()`or`createFromFile()` with `Room.databaseBuilder()`

```
Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase.class, "Sample.db")
.createFromAsset("myapp.db") //myapp.db in the assets folder
.build()
```

more from docs https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate#kotlin